# Jscroll not working after ajax data load in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have a problem in my project. I am using jscroll in my project to show data in infinite scroll. When I load data by page refreshing it works fine. But when I load data via ajax it shows previous value. I think the problem is occured because I did not reiniatiate the value after ajax call. Here is my code

```
$('ul.pagination').hide();
    $(function() {
        $('.tourpackagesearch').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true,
            loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" src="/newsite/images/Blocks-1s-200px.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
            padding: 0,
            nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
            contentSelector: 'div.tourpackagesearch',
            callback: function() {
                $('ul.pagination').remove();
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $('.same-height').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
                    var sidebar_ads = jQuery('#sidebar_ads').outerHeight();
                    jQuery('.filter_sidebar').css({"min-height":sidebar_ads});
                    $('.package_single').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
                }, 600);                
            }
        });
    });
```

And the div that is appent id

```
<div class="package_gap tourpackagesearch" id="tourpackagesearch"></div>
```

and for pagination I use

```
{{ $tourpackages->appends(Request::all())->links() }}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the jscroll function again, when your ajax call succeeds?

Comment: Yes I added the same method from where the ajax page is loaded

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem @HabibHassan? I am in a same situation now.